# sql query to count votes, groub by candidate_id, position_id

Tags: mysql, sql

table VOTES

| id | voters_id | candidate_id | positions_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xxx | 18 | 6 |
| 2 | xxx | 18 | 6 |
| 3 | xxx | 18 | 6 |
| 4 | xxx | 18 | 6 |
| 5 | xxx | 19 | 6 |
| 6 | xxx | 19 | 6 |
| 7 | xxx | 22 | 20 |
| 8 | xxx | 22 | 20 |

table POSITIONS

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | president |
| 20 | mayor |

table candidates

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | mark |
| 19 | john |
| 22 | eddie |

I HAVE THESE THEERE TABLES, I NEED A QUERY FOR THIS OUTPUT

| total_votes | candidate_id | candidate_name | position_id | position_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 18 | mark | 6 | president |
| 2 | 19 | mark | 6 | president |
| 2 | 22 | eddie | 20 | mayor |

Comment: why doesn t  format it?

Comment: You were just missing a new line between the text and the markdown table. For some reason stackoverflow's preview shows it correctly, but then when you submit it screws up the formatting.

Comment: Looks like you just need to join and aggregate to get this result. Have you written out any sql to solve this yet? Which part are you confused/unsure about (joining or aggregating)?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as total_votes, candidate_id, position_id FROM votes GROUP BY candidate_id, position_id;
<br>
this works, the problem starts when I need to add also name and title

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) as total_votes, votes.candidate_id, votes.position_id, candidates.firstname, candidates.lastname, positions.description FROM votes, candidates, positions WHERE candidates.id = votes.candidate_id AND votes.position_id = positions.id GROUP BY candidate_id, position_id;
i did this to add name and title, it works but only for one positions let say for the president one, but it doesn t show the other one for the mayor

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
select v.total_votes,
       v.candidate_id, 
       c.name as candidate_name,
       v.position_id ,
       p.title as position_name 
from (select  COUNT(*) as total_votes,
              candidate_id,
              position_id
      from votes
      GROUP BY candidate_id, position_id
  ) as v
INNER JOIN  positions p on v.position_id=p.id
INNER JOIN  candidates c on c.id=v.candidate_id ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> total_votes   candidate_id    candidate_name  position_id position_name
>   4             18               mark           6          president
>   2             19               john           6          president
>   2             22               eddie         20          mayor
> ```

*Note*. Aggregation always comes after the join, that's why you need to do the aggregation on a subquery

https://dbfiddle.uk/7q9GUm0y

> can i ask, if i would add the percentage, counting the SUM of total
> votes, on the votes obteined from a single candidate, how should i do
> it?

```
select v.total_votes,
       round(((v.total_votes * 100) / temp.tot_voters),2) AS Percentage,
       concat(round(((v.total_votes * 100) / temp.tot_voters),2),'%') AS Percentage_1,
       v.candidate_id, 
       c.name as candidate_name,
       v.position_id ,
       p.title as position_name
from (select  COUNT(*) as total_votes,
              candidate_id,
              position_id
      from votes
      GROUP BY candidate_id, position_id
  ) as v
CROSS JOIN (select count(voters_id) as tot_voters  from votes) temp  
INNER JOIN  positions p on v.position_id=p.id
INNER JOIN  candidates c on c.id=v.candidate_id ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/wBTbVVlf

Comment: it works my friend, can i ask, if i would add the percentage, counting the SUM of total votes, on the votes obteined from a single candidate, how should i do it?

Comment: select v.total_votes, v.candidate_id, c.photo, c.firstname as candidate_name,c.lastname as candidate_lastname, v.position_id , p.description as position_firstname, total_votes *100/ SUM(total_votes) OVER () AS percentage from (select COUNT(*) as total_votes, candidate_id, position_id from votes GROUP BY candidate_id, position_id) as v INNER JOIN positions p on v.position_id=p.id INNER JOIN candidates c on c.id=v.candidate_id where v.position_id = 8 ORDER BY percentage DESC;

Comment: this is how i added, the percentage